# sql strip non-number characters to do avg (average) function on column like "$12.39"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3 & postgresql

I have column like -> formatted_price: "$17.99"

How can I use avg on this column?

I tried :

```
@items = Item.where(:user_id => @category.user_id, :asin => [@category.asins[0..-2].split(',')]).select("asin as asin, title as title, avg(sales_rank) as avg_rank, avg(formatted_price) as avg_price").group(:asin, :title)
```

getting an error cuz of avg(formatted_price) as avg_price

Comment: Storing numeric data as a string is a bad code-smell. Can you ***guarantee*** that all data is in the format you described?  Or might some be different?

Comment: Yup:) I'm thinking to change it :) just curious if that can be done by one select :)

Comment: currency in particular is problematic - there are reasons most folks use integers for storing money

Comment: Look up `REPLACE()` or `SUBSTR()` to get rid of the `'$'` and `CAST()` to coerce the string into a numeric data type.  Then you'll be able to average the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
AVG(CAST(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM formatted_price) AS NUMERIC))
```

Better solution: change the column to a more suitable type, eg money or fixed precision numeric, and format it only when needed for display purposes.

**Update**: seems from the comments that the column is not formatted uniformly the way it was described in the OP. Although you could follow the suggestion from MatBailie and use substring with a regex to extract the numeric portion to get an average, to me it just does not make sense to take an average of a bunch of monetary values in different currencies.

So, either add a where clause to limit the query to those that are in the currency you want, or go back and rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you:) I'm getting this error PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
I also have values like CDN$23.32,￥104,...

Comment: @whitesiroi - So, when I asked if you can ***guarantee*** all the data was in the format you suggest, ***why*** did your response start with `Yup:)`???

Comment: I'm sorry. yes, sometimes I don't have any value in that column.

Comment: @whitesiroi - look up how to use `substring()` with regular expressions.  I'm not going to do that work for you if you can't include the correct information in the question, *or* in response to being asked directly.